# Search JPA entities that contain Lists using fields in those Lists

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

Let's say we have an entity named `Foo`.  This Foo entity contains a List of `Bar` entities.  A Bar entity has a `name`.

We persist a number of Foo records.

Now, I present the user with a JSP page to search for Foo records.  One input field I give them is Bar name.  What is a good way to inflate a `List<Foo>` that matches the user's requested Bar name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe JPQL will handle this for you without a problem.

```
select f from Foo f join f.bar b where b.name = :name
```

Comment: Very cool.  How will the speed of the query scale as the database gets large?

Comment: It should do a sql join just like you would in normal sql. You could try it and turn on show_sql (or the config equivalent for your JPA implementation provider) and see the sql that is generated if you are concerned.

Comment: For future readers, I passed this query into `.createQuery`, called `.setParameter` to set the name, and called `.getResultList` to get my `List<Foo>`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback since I wasn't in a place to actually test it. Glad it worked.

Comment: What if I have several `List<Bar>`?  I wouldn't want to do the joins for bar1, and then duplicate those joins for bar2.  Is there a way I could group them in the JPQL?

Comment: JPQL works on your JPA associations (one-to-many, many-to-many, etc.) I would assume that if Foo had multiple `List<Bar>` properties that it would be joining on different criteria, in which case you would have to do multiple joins anyway, right?